# Recursive method stuck in if statement

Tags: python, methods

I'm stuck with a method within a class that should be recursively calling itself in some cases.

```
def request(self, reqs, **kwargs):
    if not self.token:
        self.get_session_token()
    params = {}
    params["token"] = self.token
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        params[key] = value
    url = "https://" + self.ip + ":" + self.port + "/" + reqs
    req = requests.get(url, params, verify=False)
    if req.json()['ok'] == False:
        self.token = None
        return self.request(reqs, **kwargs)
    else:
        return req
```

The `return self.request(reqs, **kwargs)` line is where the code shall call the method again. However, the code just jumps back to the if statement enclosing it.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

There is code using the class providing this method. The method is executed every few minutes. If the "token" became invalid in the meantime, the if server will return `"ok" == False` and therefore `self.token` is set to `None` and the method shall be called again to request a new token -> `self.get_session_token()`.

Comment: What makes you think it jumps back to the `if` statement?

Comment: This won't jump back to your if.

Comment: Is this essentially just a while loop (ending when `req.json()['ok'] == True`) or am I missing what changes between the initial call and the recursive call?

Comment: You are modifying neither `reqs` nor `kwargs` before/in your `if` block, so you've simply asked your recursion to be indefinite.

Comment: @Gooey Unfortunately it does. And, believe me, I find it just a confusing.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye See my earlier comment. Sorry, for not providing this information.

Comment: Sorry if you find the question a bit silly but: You didn't set a breakpoint on the `if req.json()['ok'] == False:` and pressed run at the return part right?

Comment: @limbo I set a breakpoint at self.token = None and the code stopped there. The I stepped into and it executed the recursive method call but just continues executing the if statement.

Comment: Paste the return value of `req.json()` into the question at a point where you think it `req.json()['ok']` should be truthy. Also, your whole `params` construction seems a little silly. Just add `kwargs['token'] = self.token` and pass in kwargs directly.

Comment: can you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and remove the other breakpoints? Also a stack trace would be appreciated.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Good point about the silly code. Sorry, that's my first python project. I think you might have nailed the problem. It seems the server is something returing 403 instead of a proper JSON message.